# c# Assertion to check if button is not available anymore - test

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assertion

I am new with Assertions.
I want to check whit an assertion if the cookie button is not on the page anymore.
I am using C# with selenium and NUnit to test with. I am also using page object modelling.

Hope someone can help me.

This is my page opbject page.

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MakroTest
{
    class LandingPage
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        public IWebElement CookieButton => driver.FindElement(By.Id("cookie-bar-btn"));
        public IWebElement AlgemeneVoowaarden => driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Algemene voorwaarden"));
        public IWebElement Contact => driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Contact"));
        public IWebElement InlogCode => driver.FindElement(By.Id("FormModel_PromotionName"));
        public IWebElement Wachtwoord => driver.FindElement(By.Id("FormModel_Secret"));
        public IWebElement InlogButton => driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("button-secondary"));

        public void OpenWebsite()
        {
            driver.Url = DELETED THIS BECAUSE OF PRIVACY REASONS
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); ;
        }

        public void ClickCookieButton()
        {
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            CookieButton.Click();
        }

        //Assert ClickCookieButton - geen button meer zichtbaar  WERKT NOG NIET
            public bool AssertCookieButtonDisplayed()
        {
            bool isDisplayed = CookieButton.Displayed;
            return isDisplayed;
        }


    }
}
```

And this is my test page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


namespace MakroTest
{
    class LoginTest
    {
       IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

      //  [SetUp]



    [Test]
      public void ShouldBeAbleToClickCookies()
        {
            LandingPage home = new LandingPage();  //Initialize the page by calling its reference
            home.OpenWebsite();
            home.ClickCookieButton();
            // assert toevoegen  
            Assert.Null(home.AssertCookieButtonDisplayed());
            home.CloseBrowser();
         }
```

I know that there is something wrong but I cannot see what.
Also did check google etc.  Hope someone can help me.
Thank you for your great help.

Comment: Your code is clicking the button before checking it is there.  Perhaps you just need to reorder these two lines ?

Comment: That is right because first the button needs to be clicked.
After it I will check with the assertion if the button has been clicked.

Comment: But, the second time you visit this page, the button won't be there, because you clicked it previously.

Comment: That is true.
Luckly the code from Sers  did what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get `NoSuchElementException` error if the element not exist anymore in the dom, while trying to to execute `CookieButton.Displayed`. You can use try/catch and ignore error like below:

```
public bool AssertCookieButtonDisplayed()
{
    bool isDisplayed = false;
    try {
        isDisplayed = CookieButton.Displayed;
    }
    catch{}

    return isDisplayed;
}
```

Comment: This made it work!  Had to change also this Assert.False(home.AssertCookieButtonDisplayed());   but now it is working.  Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static bool existsElement(IWebDriver _driver)
       {


        try
        {

            _driver.FindElement(by);

        }

        catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message : " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message : " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }
```

You May try to check element with this one and also let it return as a boolean.